# Is there any way to access Java library from flash?

Tags: java, flash

Flash is great tool for animations. I was wondering if I could send events to Java and receive results back. In other words call some functions in flash and get their results.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) would probably be the best way. Unforutanetly its unclear if it supports Action Script (Wikipedia says it does).

Your next best bet is to make a REST interface in Java for your Action Script to call in which case you should look at JAX-RS ([Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) implementation being my first choice).

If you need a true event based system (the messages are bidirectional and asynchronous) you should look into RabbitMQ or MOM in general. In which case you would use JSON to send messages back in forth to Java and flash.

Comment: It does not I think. The reference provided on wikipedia has no information about action script. So I removed it from Wikipedia article :)

Answer (score 0):

We use [PureMVC](http://www.puremvc.org/) for this.  It allows you to map objects on both sides and deals with type conversions, and cleanly separates concerns using MVC.

Comment: I am sorry I did not get it. Can you explain a bit more how it can be used to call Java functions from Flash action script?